# Recovering from botched install of Pip3, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, python

I think need to have the latest version of PIP3 for building the latest version of a program from source, so when I ran PIP3 and couldn't build the program, I upgraded it like it suggested, and now it doesn't work at all anymore. I think what happened was:

`pip install --upgrade pip` - ran this, it didn't really work

`sudo pip install --upgrade pip` - told me for some reason I should use `sudo -H`. One funny thing about my install is that I changed the username on it (keeping the same account), having taken over a job, so sometimes weird things pop up.

`pip3 install git+https://github.com/jbarlow83/OCRmyPDF.git` - Getting towards what I want to do, install OCRmyPDF. I think it failed with a syntax error, which is why I wanted to upgrade the PIP. This second time it probably didn't work at all.

`sudo -H pip install --upgrade pip` - Trying the `sudo -H` thing now.

Ran the `pip3 install...` again as above, no dice.

I've closed and re-opened the terminal a few times. Here's what I'm dealing with now. Quite stuck.

```
$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
$ which pip3
$ sudo pip3 install git+https://github.com/jbarlow83/OCRmyPDF.git
[sudo] password for CoolDude: 
sudo: pip3: command not found
$ pip3 install git+https://github.com/jbarlow83/OCRmyPDF.git
The program 'pip3' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install python3-pip
$ sudo apt install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

This is all super confusing - any clarity would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure how you broke `pip3`, but try reinstalling it: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-pip`

Comment: Are these the instructions you're following? https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#ubuntu-16-04-lts or these? https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installing-head-revision-from-sources

Comment: The latter. I wanted the latest JBIG2 stuff for smaller file sizes. I'm just now noticing ocrmypdf requires python 3.6, and I most likely only have the 3.5 that's available for 16.04. What a mess!